# Is there any standard to index the basic colors

Tags: graphics, image-processing, core-graphics

I am wondering if there is standard to index the basic colors like red, blue etc

Comment: do you mean color names? or hex values? or some other id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ordering by hue (as in [Hue, Saturation, Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

You get something like this:

[image]

One problem with this approach is that you need to introduce a discontinuity somewhere if you want to have a scale with two extremes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the information you need - right from the specification:

[CSS Color Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/)

look in section - 4.3. Extended color keywords